# Ratingbar not taking all available space

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have a listview of ratingbar where user needs to rate different items(images) on scale of 1 to 7. I have used a linearlayout with imageview and ratingbar as the layout for my listview. However for some unknown reason ratingbar doesn't take up the complete available space and my last star is shown incomplete.

[image]

And my layout file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:stepSize="1.0" >
    </RatingBar>

</LinearLayout>
```

I set numStars in my code. If i increase numstars to 8, same thing happens, 7 stars appears as complete and last star comes as incomplete.

Comment: I don't see any sense in using RelativeLayout here, remove it and you'll be fine.

Comment: actually i didnt had any relativelayout before, was randomly trying. No luck with or without relativelayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding offsets the content of a `View`(in your case pushing the content to the right) so instead of:

```
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
```

try to use:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
```